# How can I use the free version of Qt to create a GUI for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, windows, qt, open-source

I am working on a project that requires high-medium quality GUI. I am thinking of cross compiling from Windows to Raspberry Pi or from Ubuntu to Raspberry Pi. Also, I do not know which one of those options is better.

It seems that we can not get the cross compilation toolchain of Qt on the free version of Qt and certainly we can not afford to buy the commercial version.

So what are my options? Is there a way that I can build good graphics with the  free version or should I look for a different software? Does the Qt creator work in a Raspberry Pi sort of native compilation?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this question has [a more general answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591).

Secondly, I have gotten qt-creator to run on a Pi4 running debian before.

I haven't done any serious development with it, but it works from my limited experience. (it's even in the default repos)